# About square root of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be an analytic function on open unit disc $D$ whose image is contained in  $\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0]$.

Since $f$ is always nonzero, we can define the logarithm of $f$ suitably and so is its sqaureroot.

Now my question  is that

1. Does there exist a analytic function $g$ on $D$ such that $\Re(g(z)) \ge 0$ and $g^2 = f$? for all $z$ in $D$
2. Does there exist a analytic function $g$ on $D$ such that $\Re(g(z)) \le 0$ and $g^2 = f$? for all $z$ in $D$

For constant maps it is obviously true but is it true in general?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Say $\Omega=\Bbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$. Show there is a $\sqrt z$ holomorphic in $\Omega$ with $\Re\sqrt z>0$.

Comment: Note that for any complex number $z=x+iy$ we have that $\Re z=x=0$ implies $z^2=-y^2 \le 0$, it follows that for any continuous function $g$ (on a domain) st $g^2$ has an image that avoids the closed negative real axis, we must have either $\Re g>0$ or $\Re g <0$ by connectedness

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $U=\mathbb C\setminus (-\infty,0]$ the analytic square roots are:
$$
s_1(r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta})=r^{½}\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta/2},\quad
s_2(r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta})=-r^{½}\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta/2},
$$
where $r>0$ and $\vartheta\in(-\pi,\pi)$. So
$$
s_1[U]=\{r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}: -\pi/2<\vartheta<\pi/2\}=\{x+iy\in\mathbb C: x>0\}, \\
s_2[U]=\{r\mathrm{e}^{i\vartheta}: \pi/2<\vartheta<3\pi/2\}=\{x+iy\in\mathbb C: x<0\}.
$$
So indeed, both a. and b. hold, since the square roots of $f$ are
$$
s_1\circ f \quad\text{and}\quad s_2\circ f.
$$